# how to update word file - excel file link in batch?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Word file A has about 100 charts, all of them are linked to about a dozen excel files under folder B.

Now, to try something new, I made a copy: Word file A1 and folder B1.

However, all charts in A1 are still linking to folder B, as the link was defined as \\machineName\sharedFolder\B\b_a.xls, b_b.xls...etc.

Is there a way to update A1's links to poing to excel files under folder B1?

I'm using word 97 and excel 97.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word won't know where to find the files if the the location of the word file or target directory name is changed, therefore you will need to modify the paths in the document manually.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to show field codes <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and then do a regular find and replace to substitute **"\B\"** for **"\B1\"**.

Comment: you are the man! :D